# Periodic Custom WorkManager not Triggering doWork()

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am implementing a custom WorkManager (with AppStartup & Hilt) for a periodic task but after a lot of tinkering, researching and waiting the task is not firing off.

Below is my set-up

### Worker Class

Overrides `doWork()` returning `Result.success()` or `Result.error()`. I have a Companion work with a static `schedule()` to set up **Constraints**, ***Request*** and call    **`WorkManager.getInstance(context)`**

```
class ScoresWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted private val context: Context,
    @Assisted params: WorkerParameters,
    private val db: ScoresDatabase,
    private val api: ScoresAPI
) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    private val dao = db.dao
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        Timber.i("DoWork Called")
        return try {
            val response = api.getFixturesByDate()

            dao.clearFixtures()
            dao.insertFixtures(response.response.map { it.toEntity() })
            Result.success()
        
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.i("WorKError - Exception")
            Result.failure(workDataOf(SCORES_WORKER_ERROR_KEY to e.localizedMessage))
        }
    }

    companion object {

        private const val SCORES_WORKER_ID = "scores_worker"
        fun schedule(context: Context) {

            Timber.i("companion Obj schedule() called")
            val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build()

            val request = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<ScoresWorker>(
                15, TimeUnit.MINUTES, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES
            ).setConstraints(constraints)
                .build()

            WorkManager.getInstance(context)
                .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                    SCORES_WORKER_ID, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, request
                )
        }
    }
}
```

### Helper Class

Singleton helper class to call the above `ScoresWorker.schedule(context)` and ensure WorkManager is only initialized once and there is only one instance.

```
@Singleton
class WorkManagerInitializer @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context, ) {

    private var isInitialized: Boolean = false
    fun initializeWorkManager() {

        Timber.i("initialization called - value: $isInitialized")
        if (isInitialized) return
        isInitialized = true
        ScoresWorker.schedule(context)
    }
}
```

### OnStart

To improve app startup performance I remove heavy stuff like scheduling WorkManager from the app startup sequence moving it instead to onStart().

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var initializationHelper: WorkManagerInitializer
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent { .... }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        initializationHelper.initializeWorkManager()
    }
}
```

### Application Class and

The Application class implement the **`Configuration.Provider`** interface

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class InstantScoreApp : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
    override fun onCreate() { ... }

    @Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration {
        return Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
    }
}
```

### Manifest

First tried this approach as described on the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/configuration/custom-configuration#remove-default)

```
...
<provider
   android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
   tools:node="remove"
         >

        </provider>-->
    </application>
```

This too did not work.

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge">

            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup"
                tools:node="remove" />

        </provider>
```

I am on **`work-runtime-ktx v 2.8.0`** and **`startup-runtime v1.1`** .

I need help on what I could possibly be missing for this set-up to work. Pls Help.

Comment: is there any error shown in logcat  and also check internet is available or not?

Comment: please also  check whether you add your InstantScoreApp application class in the manifest file or not.

Comment: Hi Tausif, no errors caught so far and have tried both on the emulator and a physical device. Internet is on and have applied internet permision. Have added the application class to the manifest through `android:name=".InstantScoreApp"` tag.

Comment: please check below library is added in your gradle file or not .


   implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0"
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0")
    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.39.1"

Comment: it seems you extend CoroutineWorker in ScoresWorker class. You may try with worker class instead of CoroutineWorker. I also provide details in the answer section.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I will give it ago

Comment: and also try with removing   "private val db: ScoresDatabase,
    private val api: ScoresAPI" in construction ScoresWorker class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my working code,
at manifest file :

```
 android:name=".MainApplication"

<provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            tools:node="remove">
        </provider>
```

at app build gradle file :

```
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0"
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0")
    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.39.1"
```

At MainApplication class :

```
 @Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

 override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
               
        context = applicationContext
        WorkManager.initialize(this, workManagerConfiguration)


    }
     override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()

    companion object {
        lateinit var context: Context

    }
}
```

My periodic worker class :

```
@HiltWorker
class PeriodicWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted appContext: Context, @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    val repository: Repository
) : Worker(appContext, workerParams){

    override  fun doWork(): Result {
        try {

            val applicationContext = applicationContext
            // do nceessary work
            return Result.success()


        } catch (e: Exception) {

            Log.e("UploadWorker", e.printStackTrace().toString())
            return Result.failure()
        }
    }



}
```

initialize periodic worker in activity class :

```
  private lateinit var periodicWorkRequest: WorkRequest
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        periodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<PeriodicWorker(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()
                
 WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueue(periodicWorkRequest)

    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for posting your working code, I can't believe the whole issue was being caused by a missing `@HiltWorker` annotation on the `Worker` class!  In the background. The WorkManager was triggering alright `NoSuchMethodException` on the LogCat which I didn't spot until I looked at your Working Code. Greatly appreciated, You are legend!!

Comment: Happy to see, my given code helped you to identify the issue.